# Getting Invalid JSON response in the datatable

Tags: json, datatables

I am getting the data from api and I want it to display in the datatable but I am getting the Invalid JSON response.
here is what I am doing .
My response from API

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "order_id": "11204",
      "ins_url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/BNXavo0hdBH/",
      "quantity_total": "50",
      "price": "0.0600",
      "quantity_done": "0",
      "status": "0",
      "added_time": "1481779270"
    },
    {
      "order_id": "11205",
      "ins_url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/BNXavo0hdBH/",
      "quantity_total": "50",
      "price": "0.0600",
      "quantity_done": "0",
      "status": "0",
      "added_time": "1481779413"
    }]
}
```

My data-table code:

```
jQuery.post(
        ajaxlink.ajax_url,
        {
            'action': 'getorderhistoryapi'
        },
        function (response) {
$('#ViewUserDatatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,

    columns: [
    {data: "order_id"},
    { data: "ins_url" },
    { data: "quantity_total" },
    { data: "price" },
    { data: "quantity_done" },
    { data: "status" },
    { data: "added_time" }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: Where do you specify the JSON source?

Comment: The Json you get is valid, so the problem should be at the insert. Are the column types correct for these values?

Comment: Could you please provide code where you actually set data json to DataTable?

Comment: @Stan I didn't understand what you are asking for. I have provided all the code which I am trying

Comment: Add `data: response.data,` to the DataTable options, then it will work.

Comment: and I suppose in columns definition need to change 'data' to 'title'. I believe this could be a good example https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: @Stan not true; OP does it correct, he just need to define `data` for the dataTable.

Comment: @davidkonrad After adding `data: response.data,` and changing the columns definition to to 'title'. I am getting error `Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`

Comment: @ElsieHamilton but you should not change anything to title. Title is column headers, has nothing to do with data.

Comment: @ElsieHamilton  Redefining your whole datatable every ajax request isn't the best way to do this but add "destroy: true" to your options and that should do the trick.